# PUT not updating Pipedrive API (Python wrapper)

Tags: python, pipedrive-api

Here's a brief description of what I'm trying to do:

- get a field's value
- multiply that value by a constant
- update the field with the adjusted value

I am using a nice wrapper found here: https://github.com/hiway/pipedrive-api

Here is my code:

```
from pipedrive import Pipedrive
pd = Pipedrive('API_token')
                   # ^ insert API token                  
EAAR = pd.deals.get(id=693)       ## parse info from given deal/field
Current_value = float(EAAR.value) ## convert value to decimal
print 'Previous value was ', Current_value

New_value = Current_value * 0.96
print 'New Value is ', New_value

pd.deals.put({
    id:693,
    'value': New_value})

EAAR2 = pd.deals.get(id=693)
print EAAR2.value
```

So expected output would be:

```
>>>Previous value was  5.0
>>>New Value is  4.8
>>>4.8
```

However, I'm getting:

```
>>>Previous value was  5.0
>>>New Value is  4.8
>>>5
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What HTTP status code and content was returned from the `PUT` operation?

Comment: When I turn on debugging, I get:
`send: 'GET /v1/deals/693?api_token=[API_token]
HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.Pipedrive.com\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/2.7.3 Windows/7\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: nginx
header: Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2015 17:58:37 GMT
header: Content-Type: application/json
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
...

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is with my Json command in lines 11-13, but I'm honestly new to interacting with APIs anyway and I'm not sure I understand the PUT command or JSON well enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it was a syntax issue, found after extensive debugging. The new code now appears like this:

```
pd.deals.put(
    id=693,
    data={
    "value":New_value})
```

Where the change is reflected by moving the deal id outside of the data field.

Answer (score 0):

your put is probably failing. put quotes around id:

pd.deals.put({
    'id':693,
    'value': New_value})

Comment: Tried that, Shawn. Still nothing :(